# How to underline the whole text of a WinRT TextBox?

Tags: textbox, windows-runtime

I want to set the underline for the whole text in a TextBox like setting TextDecorations in WPF TextBox. But there is no similar property in WinRT TextBox. So can anyone please suggest any solution to achieve my requirement?

Note: I don't want to use RichEditBox

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, there is a TextDecorations property for TextBoxes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I need this for WinRT textbox. but wrongly mentioned as WPF. sorry for wrong  info. Now i edited.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox doesn't support underline. RichEditBox is designed for that sort of thing. Why don't you want to use it? You can set underlines with no other visible difference from a TextBox.

If you don't need editing then you can apply underlines in a TextBlock:

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Underline>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </Underline>
    </TextBlock>
```